# while loop using OR

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string player1, player2;
    char choice1, choice2;

    cout<<"Enter the name of player number one"<<endl;
    cin>> player1;
    cout<<"Enter the name of player number two"<<endl;
    cin>>player2;
    //choose choice 

    while((choice1 !='X')||  ( choice1 !='O' ) )
    {
        cout<<"Play number one choose X or O"<<endl;
        cin>>choice1;        
    }
```

while loop never ends even when I enter X or O. I want it to end when either value is entered

Answer (score 4):

That expression can literally never be false. I think you meant

```
while((choice1 !='X') && ( choice1 !='O' ))
```

Comment: To phrase in English because sometimes it helps: "While the choice is not X and is not O, ask for another choice."

Answer (score 1):

The while statement you have will never be false. Change the `||` to `&&`:

```
while((choice1 !='X') && ( choice1 !='O' ) )
```

Think about it. Imagine choice1='O':

```
while((choice1 !='X')||  ( choice1 !='O' ) )
        ^true                 ^false                    == true
```

Now choice='X':

```
while((choice1 !='X')||  ( choice1 !='O' ) )
         ^ false     ||       ^true                     == true
```

For more info on this check out [De Morgan's Laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws)

Answer (score 0):

it is because of the OR (||) condition. If you enter 'X', it evaluates false on the first expression but evaluates true on the second expression, so while loop will never be false. Use "&&" instead.